# Kernel and Range of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

So the question is let $T:M_{2\times2}\to\Bbb R$ be defined by
$T(A) = \operatorname{tr}(A)$.
Find bases for the kernel and range of the linear transformation $T$.

Could someone explain how to solve this as I don't quite understand what the question is asking

Answer (score 1):

Note that $T$ is surjective since for $a\in\Bbb R$ we have $T(A)=a$ where
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Of course, this implies $\{1\}$ is a basis for $\DeclareMathOperator{Image}{Image}\Image T$.

The Rank-Nullity theorem states
$$
\dim\ker T+\dim\Image T=\dim M_{2\times 2}
$$
Since $\Image T=\Bbb R$ and since
\begin{align*}
\dim\Bbb R &= 1 & \dim M_{2\times 2}&=4
\end{align*}
it follows that
$$
\dim\ker T=4-1=3
$$
So, to find a basis for $\ker T$, it suffices to find three linearly independent matrices in the kernel of $T$. But it can easily be checked that
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
&&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&&
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
are three such matrices.